# Передача координат модели в surf HLSL

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Пишу шейдер для Unity - есть объект и его свечение должно меняться в зависимости от координат. С шейдерами раньше не работал, но из уроков, видео и прочих мануалов, в том числе офф. юнити, выяснил, что вся магия происходит в методе surf шейдера. Меняется значение Emission. Осталось только установить зависимость от координат самого объекта. В других примерах видел что делается это в методе vert, куда собственно и пробрасываются данные о координатах пикселя, но как обратиться к этим данным в методе surf?

На текущий момент имею такую заготовку:

```
CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
          o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb;
          o.Emission = (float3)0.5f;
        }
ENDCG
```

Comment: Вам нужны координаты центральной точки модели в surf секции шейдера?

Comment: Я не до конца уверен, какие координаты я могу получить в шейдере, но да. Либо модели, либо пикселя, который обрабатывается. В моем случае особой разницы нет. Пиксель, если это, возможно даже лучше.

Comment: Я почитал про pipeline видеопроцессора и на сколько понял, сначала идет обработка в вертексном шейдере, где у меня и доступны координаты вершины, после чего запускается работа пиксельного шейдера. Может быть можно создать переменную и запомнить координаты в вертексном шейдере, а потом использовать в пиксельном?

Comment: Смотря что требуется, в описанном Вами в комментарии варианте из каждой вершины будут переданы свои значения, и они будут интерполированы. так же можно задать одну переменную на весь шейдер. это разные сценарии

Comment: Изначально мне требуется менять свечение в зависимости от координат, так что, думаю, центр модели меня устроит.

Comment: Я тогда не совсем понимаю зачем вообще понадобился кастомный шейдер, у стандартного есть переменная, которую можно устанавливать перед отрисовкой объекта, так же как и положение подели пришлось бы передавать, можно конечно, но есть ли в этом смысл?

Comment: Вечером буду проверять. А можно подробнее что за переменная в стандартном шейдере и как ее установить? Перед отрисовкой - это средствами С# или в самом шейдере?

Comment: Вам ответили примерно то же самое что я имел в виду, но можно пойти и Вашим путем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Зависимости от координат" ты можешь считать сам в `Update () {}` и передавать своему свойству шейдера `_Dependence("dependence", Float) = 0`. Чтобы у каждого экземпляра (если их больше одного) было своё значение у всех должен быть свой экземпляр материала `gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = Instantiate<Material>(YourMat);`. И передаёшь посчитанную зависимость `gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetFloat("_Dependence", YourDependence);`

Comment: Спасибо. Оставлю как запасной вариант, но изначально предполагается что задача должна быть решена без помощи кода на шарпе. То есть только средствами шейдера.

Comment: Я тоже в шейдерах не ахти, но вы уверены, что для этих целей вам нужен StandartSurfaceShader? Возможно вам нужен ImageEffectShader, где в frag вы обращаетесь к i.uv, который вычисляется тем самым Vert

Comment: Судя по методичкам Unity - если работаете с освещением - используйте Surface Shader. Почитаю про ImageEffect.